# The argument type 'Future<dynamic> Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String?)?'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, mobile-application, flutter-local-notification

I am using flutter local notification but it doesn't work and it suddenly makes my app shuts down. Here's my code.

```
  initializeNotifications() async {
var initializationSettingsAndroid =
    AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/launcher_icon');
var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings();
var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
    android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
var flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
    onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
```

}

```
Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
if (payload != null) {
  debugPrint('notification payload: ' + payload);
}
await Navigator.push(
  context,
  new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MedicineReminder()),
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
  initializationSettings,
  onSelectNotification: (payload) {
    if (payload != null) {
      onSelectNotification(payload!);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: or simply use : onSelectNotification: (payload) => onSelectNotification(payload), and then make payload in the function nullable